# "Report Server Central Administration Feature" is missing in Central Administration Site collection features

Tags: 2016, reporting-services

I am using SharePoint Server 2016 and SQL Server 2016 SP1. I installed "Reporting Services - SharePoint" feature on the Application server(Custom Role) and "Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products" feature on the Web Front-end Server. I am also able to create the "SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application".

We have migrated from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 and have a Document library with below reporting content types:

> - Report Builder Model
> - Report Builder Report
> - Report Data Source

After migration I see some faulty content types in target environment. Refer to below screen-shot.

[image]

from the above image I was able to understand the features may not be activated. But I could not find the reporting services features in Central Administration and site collection to activate them. Below are the features am looking for.

> - "Power View Integration Feature" site collection feature.
> - "Report Server Central Administration Feature" central administration site collection feature.

Comment: check if the reporting service instance is running? also RS is associated with Web application?

Answer (score 0):

Install reporting services in sharepoint 2016 server then it will work.

installation of reporting services is in this blog - https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2016/03/configuring-ssrs-2016-integrated-mode-sharepoint-2016/